# How to migrate SP07 content to SP13 for our end users

Tags: 2013, content-database, information-management

I work for a law firm and we are going to be upgrading to SP13 next year, we are looking for an effective/efficient way to move our end user's content from 07 to 13. Has anyone done this recently or plan to? How did your company/firm manage this process?

Answer (score 1):

If the content is too small ,please do not use a 3rd party tool because the cost involved would be too much . If data is large you need to use tools , use Metalogix,Quest or any other 3rd party tools.

We used the below approach.
- Assessing and updating your 2007 Environment
- Planning for an interim 2010 environment with the emphasis on SQL Server
- Planning for and setting up the 2013 Environment
- Initial database migration from 2007 to 2010 and testing on 2010
- Final database migration from 2010 to 2013

Answer (score 0):

Without any third-party tools, this is a two step process.  You first need to attach your content databases to SharePoint 2010 to upgrade them to that level.  Then you can attach your content databases to SharePoint 2013.

If you are wanting to migrate directly, or only migrate certain content, you will need to use third-party migration tools.